# Transformation from position space wavefunction to momentum space wavefunction

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, hilbert-space, wavefunction, fourier-transform

In the derivation here, how can bra p go inside the integral?

As far as my understanding, the meaning of bra p is integral dx(ket p)* .........

The arguments in both integrals is x. Then, how can we merge those two integrals?

Let me give an example:
integral(x (integral(x dx))dx) is not the same as integral(integral(x^2 dx) dx)

[image]

Comment: Why do you think $\langle p|\equiv\int\mathrm dx\ (|p\rangle)^*$ ? That is not the case.

Comment: Please write whatever text and equations are needed for your question. Posting images is not appreciated, because it's harder to read, and impossible to search and edit.

Comment: Also, could you use [mathjax](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/notation)
, please, to make this easier to read?

Comment: @Nihar Karve That is what Griffiths introduced for a bra vector

Comment: Page 152. 1st formula

Answer (score 1):

So we are given a time-dependent quantum mechanical state $|\mathcal{S}(t)\rangle\in\mathcal{H}$ (from Griffiths, Intro to QM, p148). We can get the standard *position representation wavefunction* via a projection $\psi(x,t)=\langle x|\mathcal{S}(t)\rangle$, where $|x\rangle$ is the eigenvector of the position operator $\hat{x}$ with eigenvalue $x$. Similarly, we can get the *momentum representation wavefunction* via a projection $\phi(p,t)=\langle p|\mathcal{S}(t)\rangle$. Here $|p\rangle$ is an eigenvector of the momentum operator $\hat{p}$, with eigenvalue $p$.

Now we assume that the sets $\{|x\rangle\}$ and $\{|p\rangle\}$ are complete and thus we can express the identity operator in the following way$$\mathbb{I}=\int dx|x\rangle\langle x|\quad\text{and similarly}\quad\mathbb{I}=\int dp|p\rangle\langle p|.$$Note that the first integrand is a function of $x$ and the second is a function of $p$. If we want to express $\phi(p,t)$ in terms of $\psi(x,t)$, we can make use of these identity operators. Let me explain the steps in the book. We write $$\phi(p,t)=\langle p|\mathcal{S}(t)\rangle$$which is just the definition of $\phi(p,t)$. Then we can inset the identity operator (corresponding to the position eigenstates) into the inner product without destroying the equality to get$$\phi(p,t)=\langle p|\mathcal{S}(t)\rangle=\langle p|\mathbb{I}|\mathcal{S}(t)\rangle=\langle p|\left(\int dx|x\rangle\langle x|\right)|\mathcal{S}(t)\rangle.$$Now since the integral is over $x$, we can insert $\langle p|$ and $|\mathcal{S}(t)\rangle$ into the integral (as if they were constants, this is just basic calculus) to get$$\phi(p,t)=\int dx\langle p|x\rangle\langle x|\mathcal{S}(t)\rangle.$$Using the definition of $\langle x|\mathcal{S}(t)\rangle=\psi(x,t)$, we write$$\phi(p,t)=\int dx\langle p|x\rangle\psi(x,t).$$Finally, $\langle p|x\rangle$ is just the conjugate of the projection of the momentum eigenstate to the position basis, which has a standard result. Plug this in and you're done. $|p\rangle$ is nothing but the eigenstate of the momentum operator. You can express it in terms of any basis, provided it forms a complete set. For example, you can write$$|p\rangle=\int dx|x\rangle\langle x|p\rangle.$$But that is just making use of the identity operator in the position basis, so nothing changes here. We would still end up with$$\phi(p,t)=\langle p|\mathcal{S}(t)\rangle=\int dx\langle p|x\rangle\langle x|\mathcal{S}(t)\rangle=\int dx\langle p|x\rangle\psi(x,t)$$as required.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have your edition of Griffiths (in my 1995 edition your page number is badly off; I am talking about his definition of the bra  on footnote of Chapter 3, below), but it is evident the edition you have led you to wildly misread  said definition.  First,  consider the kets that are eigenfunctions of $\hat p$ in the x-representation,
$$
|p\rangle= \int\!\! dx ~~f_p(x) |x\rangle ,
$$
where its "wavefunction" $f_p(x)= e^{ipx/\hbar}/\sqrt{2\pi\hbar}$ is just the kernel of the Fourier transform: you are merely looking at a Fourier transform!

Just as this definition maps functions $f_p(x)$ to vectors (kets $|p\rangle$), the dual linear functional
$$
\langle p| = \int\!\! dx ~~f^*_p(x)~~~~~~[...]
$$
maps bras to functions: it goes backwards: The bra is a ket-eater.

Crucially, this "instruction" of his leaves the ellipsis [...] to be what the bra "encounters next". So, the number/scalar/function produced is
$$
\langle p|x'\rangle = \int\!\! dx ~~f^*_p(x)~ \delta (x-x') = f^*_p(x')= \langle x'|p\rangle ^*,
$$
the inverse kernel of the Fourier transform, as reviewed at the bottom of the text page you scanned.  I have used *x'* to contrast the ket labels to the dummy integration variable. You, of course, recall $\langle x|x'\rangle = \delta (x-x')$.

In your example, you find, hopefully trivially, by now, that you just Fourier transform functions instead of vectors (kets) dotted onto their duals (bras). From the leading definition in this answer,
$$
\langle x'|p\rangle= \int\!\! dx ~~f_p(x) \langle x'|x\rangle = f_p(x'),
$$
the above "instruction".